# Updating subdocuments with Mongoose's doc.save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am relatively new to Mongoose and I am having trouble getting the doc.save() to work when updating a subdocument.

Currently I have this code:

```
Marksheet.findById(req.body.id, function(err, marksheet) {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        marksheet.marks[0] = req.body.mark;
        marksheet.save(function(err){
            if (err) return res.send(err);
            res.json(marksheet);
        });
```

When I run this through Node.js I get this error:

> TypeError: doc.save is not a function

If I try to only change some of the root values, I have no problems with running marksheet.save(). Also, if I use findByIdAndUpdate() instead it seems to work fine.

```
Marksheet.findByIdAndUpdate(marksheet._id, marksheet, {new: true}, function(err, newMarksheet){
            if (err) return res.send(err);
            res.json(newMarksheet);
        });
```

My question is why does the subdocument not want to save and is there a better way for me to run this update operation rather than replacing the whole document?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .save() method when creating new object of the Model and using findOne() method. you can see the example below :

```
Chat.findOne({idChatGroup : idChatGroup}, function(err,chat){
            if(err){
                res.json({
                    status : "not_ok",
                    result : "Error Query"
                })
            }else{
                if(chat){
                    var chatSave = new Chat({
                        idChatGroup : idChatGroup,
                        children : [{
                            uidUser : uidUser,
                            gcmID : gcmID
                        }]
                    }); 

                    chatSave.save(function (err,result){
                        if(err){
                            res.json({
                                status : "not_ok",
                                result : "Error Saving user"
                            });
                        }else{
                            res.json({
                                status : "ok",
                                result : "user add to group"
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    chat.children.push({
                        uidUser : uidUser,
                        gcmID : gcmID
                    });

                    chat.save(function (err,result){
                        if(err){
                            res.json({
                                status : "not_ok",
                                result : "Error Saving user"
                            });
                        }else{
                            res.json({
                                status : "ok",
                                result : "user add to group"
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }




            }
```

so when you trying to updating sub-document, you need to find the document first and then update the sub-document.

You can find the full source [here](https://github.com/Gujarats/MongooseCrud/blob/master/routes/docs.js)

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in my question as my current workaround. findOneAndUpdate is the same as findByIdAndUpdate. I was asking if there is any way to use the doc.save() method?